# bclogo: logo do not display with in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex

Could you help me please?

I am trying to get a `.pdf` file with bclogo but I receive a latex message error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `bc-fleur' not found.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
>   Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help....
>   \end{bclogo}

### I use miktex 2.9 with windows 8.1 !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grisbleu}{RGB}{224,224,224}

\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=grisbleu!90,logo=\bccrayon, couleurBord = grisbleu , couleurOmbre = grisbleu, epBarre=2.5]{Code}
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red},fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\small,fontseries=b]

tab<-read.table("grandtable.txt")

#pour ne  lire qu'une colonne#

tab$V5

\end{Verbatim}


\end{bclogo}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE uses option `logo=\bccrayon` and uses `bc-crayon.mps` as image. Should this be corrected to `logo=\bcfleur`? Is `bc-crayon.mps` found? Which TeX engine/driver you are using? Have you tried to update `bclogo`? Which version do you have?

Comment: I have Miktex 2.9 os: windows 8.1

Comment: I have istalled bclogo  refresh FNDB, and I tried with a command mktexlsr without success!

Comment: the result is the same any logo is rconignesed !( sorry for my bad enlish)

Comment: is not recognised (oups !)

Comment: BTW, you can edit the comment up to 5 min after the creation.

Comment: (a) Version: Add `\listfiles` at the start of the document, compile and get a version list at the end of the `.log` file. Most interesting version is from package `bclogo`. (b) Examples for TeX engine/driver: pdflatex; latex/dvips/ps2pdf; xelatex; latex/dvipdfmx; ... (c) Does `bc-fleur.mps` exist on your system? Which directory?

Comment: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bclogo

Comment: That is probably the answer for the second question in (c), the path looks fine. What's the difficulty answering the other questions?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\definecolor{grisbleu}{RGB}{224,224,224}

\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=grisbleu!90,logo=\bccrayon, couleurBord = grisbleu , couleurOmbre = grisbleu, epBarre=2.5]{Code}
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red},fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\small,fontseries=b]

tab<-read.table("grandtable.txt")

#pour ne  lire qu'une colonne#

tab$V5

\end{Verbatim}


\end{bclogo}%

\end{document}
```

[image]